# concatenate related records in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have tables tbl_main_new_registration and tbl_supp_compositions in my product registration database in Microsoft Access 365.

I am trying to create a sql query so that it can show me brand_name (this field is in the table 1) with all of its active_ingredients (this field in the table 2) in a single row. however, I am unable to figure it out. currently, my query is:

```
SELECT tbl_main_new_registration.[brand_name], tbl_supp_compositions.active_ingredient, tbl_supp_compositions.strength
FROM tbl_main_new_registration 
INNER JOIN tbl_supp_compositions 
ON tbl_main_new_registration.new_reg_id = tbl_supp_compositions.brand_name;
```

and it shows the following results:

[image]

and I want to achieve it as follows:

[image]

I have tried some online solutions i.e. http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html but I am unable to understand and apply it. Moreover, I tried to apply some answers from stackoverflow but i think I am unable to fully understand it.

Comment: can't you do it at application level?

Comment: I'm trying to concatenate `active_ingredient` of a `brand_name` along with its relative `strength`s. I don't know how to do that at application level?

Comment: i understand that, but access has no function for that, there a plenty of examples like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601643/access-sql-query-to-concatenate-rows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate records and GROUP BY in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624845/concatenate-records-and-group-by-in-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query using my [DJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587753/combo-box-to-select-value-w-multiple-duplicates-populating-textbox-in-form-w/62589561#62589561) function will do that:

```sql
SELECT 
    tbl_main_new_registrations.Id, 
    tbl_main_new_registrations.[Brand Name], 
    DJoin("[active_ingredient] & ': ' & [strength]","[tbl_supp_compositions]","[BrandNameId] = " & [Id] & "",": ") AS active_ingredients
FROM 
    tbl_main_new_registrations
GROUP BY 
    tbl_main_new_registrations.Id, 
    tbl_main_new_registrations.[Brand Name], 
    DJoin("[active_ingredient] & ': ' & [strength]","[tbl_supp_compositions]","[BrandNameId] = " & [Id] & "",": ")
ORDER BY 
    tbl_main_new_registrations.Id;
```

[image]

Comment: it says undefined function 'Djoin' in expression.

Comment: Because the [DJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62589561/880990) function is not a standard Access function. It has been written by @Gustav. Follow the link and copy the code from there and insert it into a VBA module..