# String.Join on a list of objects

Tags: c#, list

In C#, if I have a `List<MyObj>` where `MyObj` is a custom class with an overridden `ToString()` method such that each `MyObj` object in the List can be easily converted to a string.

How can I *join* this `List<MyObj>` with a delimiter, such as for example a pipe (|) into a single string.

So, if I had 3 MyObj objects whose ToString methods would produce AAA, BBB, CCC respectively. I would create a single string: AAA|BBB|CCC.

For a list of a simpler type, such as `List<string>`, I perform this simply as: `String.Join("|", myList.ToArray());`.  Is there a way I can do something similar to that?  Or am I forced to iterate over the Object List and use a StringBuilder to append each object's ToString in the list together?

Comment: Related (2008): *[Join collection of objects into comma-separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330493)*

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In .NET 4, you could just use:

```
var x = string.Join("|", myList);
```

.NET 3.5 doesn't have as many overloads for `string.Join` though - you need to perform the string conversion and turn it into an array explicitly:

```
var x = string.Join("|", myList.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Compare the overloads available:

- [.NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c%28v=vs.90%29)
- [.NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c%28v=vs.100%29)

Comment: Can the LINQ `Join` replace the `string.Join`?

Comment: @ÂngeloPolotto: No, they're *completely* different operations.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly with:
var x = string.Join("|", myList.Select(x => x.myProperty.ToString()).ToArray());

Answer (score 4):

[Thank you, Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540584/string-join-on-a-list-of-objects/10540609#10540609). For a more complex object I use the below:

```
string.Join("-", item.AssessmentIndexViewPoint.Select(x =>
              x.ViewPointItem.Name).ToList())
```