# Is there a way to validate that a List isn't null/empty when trying to convert a list of objects into a big string for the purpose of making a hash

Tags: c#, string, list

I've tried a few things like Modifiers?.Select and String.Join amongst some other things.  "Modifiers" here is a list of objects that have an int called Level and an enum for the Id.  It's for a game that I'm fiddling around with in Unity.

The following code works fine as long as the list isn't empty, which it frequently will be.

Also - for reference, I got the structure for this line from this question:
[String.Join on a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540584/string-join-on-a-list-of-objects)

*Edit* I forgot to mention that the error I'm getting is *ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.* If the list is empty.

```
public int Hash => $"{Id}.{String.Concat(Modifiers.Select(i => i.Id))}".GetHashCode();
```

Comment: That should work for an empty list, but for `null` you'd want to do something like `?? new string[0]` after it.

Comment: I tried this a few ways and I'm still struggling.  Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place?

public int Hash => $"{Id}.{string.Concat(Modifiers.Select(i => i.Id))?? new string[0]}".GetHashCode();

This gives me type mismatch (string and string[]).

I see what you're getting at with it though, I tried a few other things after new and it feels like I'm getting closer.

Comment: Actually it is not entirely clear how you hold your objects in list... I create my custom class with enum id field and all work pretty fine with empty list. Can you give us implementation of `Modifiers`.