# How can I get the List with a custom datatype to a string builder?

Tags: c#, list, class, .net-3.5

I have a class.

```
public class IdDetails
{
    public string transactionDate { get; set; }
    public string upnName { get; set; }
    public string movementTrade { get; set; }
    public string baseCurve { get; set; }
    public string cTolerance { get; set; }
    //17 more declarations below
}
```

Then I used it as the DataType of my List `Interface`

```
foreach(DataRow r in tbl1.Rows)
{
    InterFace.Add(new IdDetails
    {
         transactionDate = Convert.ToDateTime(r["TransDate"]).ToString(@"MM/dd/yyyy"),
         upnName = string.Empty
         movementTrade = "incoming",
         //... Somemore adding of values
    }
}
```

I have tried this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330493/join-collection-of-objects-into-comma-separated-string). However, I think it is build of strings with Single data inside each item.*I dont know the actual terminology for this*

I have tried to do it like this using my reference

```
var x = concatenate<IdDetails>(Interface, Convert.ToString, ';');
```

But I'm not getting the result i need, Instead I am getting there values

```
//output im getting
x = "DataImport2.IdDetails;" //<- this string repeated multiple times
```

[image]

**Question:** How can I directly write the contents of the my custom List to a string builder? Without me transforming it to another object. Because I can cast it to a `DataTable` and process it to a `StringBuilder`. That's a rather long process and coding.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.Join()` to achieve what you need. For example

```
string.Join(",", Interface.Select(item => item.transactionDate + " " + item.xxx + // etc etc));
```

EDIT:

Override `ToString()` in `IdDetails` to use `Reflection` to get all values of your class.

```
public class IdDetails
{
    public string transactionDate { get; set; }
    public string upnName { get; set; }
    public string movementTrade { get; set; }
    public string baseCurve { get; set; }
    public string cTolerance { get; set; }

    private static string SafeString(object s)
    {
        return s == null ? string.Empty : s.ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(IdDetails).GetProperties();
        return string.Join(",", properties.Select(prop => SafeString(prop.GetValue(this, null))).ToArray());
    }

    //17 more declarations below
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to loop or shorten the code `item.transactionDate` etc etc? because its a rather long class and could be longer depending on the requirement..

Comment: What I would do is `override` `IdDetails` `ToString()` to return the property values I want. Then have this `string.Join(",", Interface.Select(item => item.ToString());`

Comment: Can you show me how can I `override` it `ToString()` ?

Comment: Code has been updated. All properties in your class will now be used. You don't have to manually code it.

Comment: I have an error on `string.Join(";", properties.Select(prop => prop.GetValue(this, null)));` http://imgur.com/a/3ETiH

Comment: I see you're using .Net 3.5. That is causing the issue. Let me have a rework.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135009/discussion-between-johanp-and-hexxed).